# MissingMethodException error while running spock/geb test with gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle, spock, geb

I am trying to run geb test using spock. I've written everything in a groovy script, which is placed in `/src/main/groovy` and looks like below

```
import spock.lang.Specification
import geb.Browser
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

class AccessCookieInFF{
...
}

class BrowserSpec extends Specification {

  def CookieTest(){
          given: ...
          when:  ...
         then:  ...
                     }
}

def newTest= new BrowserSpec()
newTest.CookieTest()
```

running the above setup gives me

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of m
ethod: BrowserSpec.CookieTest() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

simple groovy script runs fine with my gradle set up. Can someone please point, whats wrong here. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to run tests in a so weird way?

Comment: for first method should start from lowerCase. See java convention, for second all test should start from test..

Comment: @Koloritnij  I changed the case but i still get the same exact error.can you please explain what  you mean by test should start from `test`. I dont have much knowledge in geb/spock

Comment: @Opal because I dont know of any other way. Can you point me to a different way? thanks.

Comment: I hope this help you: https://github.com/geb/geb-example-grails/tree/master/test/functional http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/ ; Test should start from test, for example testCookies. But it must in junit, in all other it just should :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working by placing groovy test file in `/src/test/groovy` and making some changes to `build.gradle` file as per the link below and running it by command `gradle test` . The test file now looks like below (i removed `class AccessCookieInFF` for other reasons)

```
import spock.lang.Specification
import geb.Browser
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

    class BrowserSpec extends Specification {
    def cookieTest(){
                    given: ...
                    when:  ...
                    then:  ...

                    }
   }
```

[This](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/build-integrations.html#gradle) was very helpful. Thanks